# Sidekiq list all jobs [queued + running]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Is there a way to get a list of all the jobs currently in the queue and running? Basically, I want to know if a job of given class is already there, I don't want to insert my other job. I've seen other option but I want to do it this way.

I can see [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API) how to get the list of jobs in the queue.

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new("mailer")
queue.each do |job|
  job.klass # => 'MyWorker'
end
```

from what I understand this will not include processing/running jobs. Any way to get them?

Comment: When you inspect the Workers using `sidekiq/api` you can see on what the workers are working on https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#workers

Answer (score 70):

if you want to list all currently running jobs from console, try this

```
workers = Sidekiq::Workers.new
workers.each do |_process_id, _thread_id, work|
  p work
end
```

a `work` is a hash.

to list all queue data.

```
queues = Sidekiq::Queue.all
queues.each do |queue|
  queue.each do |job|
    p job.klass, job.args, job.jid
  end
end
```

for a specific queue change this to `Sidekiq::Queue.new('queue_name')`

similarly you can get all scheduled jobs using `Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new`

Comment: this answer is possibly outdated: I get `NoMethodError: undefined method `klass'`

Comment: `job.klass` is still available in 2020. check https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/6c94a9dd9f3ccbbd107c6ad2336c26a305020a25/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L189

Comment: It seems like calling `job.jid` generates the following error: `NoMethodError: undefined method `jid' for #<Sidekiq::Queue:0x00007ff144076178>` Is this because we're trying to get a job ID from a queue?

Answer (score 12):

running jobs:

```rb
Sidekiq::Workers.new.each do |_process_id, _thread_id, work|
  p work
end
```

queued jobs across all queues:

```rb
Sidekiq::Queue.all.each do |queue|
  # p queue.name, queue.size
  queue.each do |job|
    p job.klass, job.args
  end
end
```

Comment: A bit of clarification: Sidekiq::Queue.all would only output jobs in progress, not the scheduled ones. As the accepted answer states, you need to use Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new to get the scheduled jobs.

Comment: @sharq Could you consider removing this answer as it is the same as the accepted?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you passed the Hash as the argument to Sidekiq when you enqueued.

```
args = {
  "student_id": 1,
  "student_name": "Michael Moore"
    }

YourWorker.perform_in(1.second,args)
```

Then anywhere from your application, you could retrieve it as following

```
      ss = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
      student_id_list = ss.map{|job| job['args'].first["student_id"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this in the ApplicationJob to check if there is already a job in the queue with same name/arguments and prevent from queue it twice

**apps/jobs/application_job.rb**

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
    

    # Check if there is the same job already queued
    around_enqueue do |job, block|
        
        existing_queued_jobs = list_queued_jobs(job.class, job.queue_name, job.arguments)
        if existing_queued_jobs.size == 0
            block.call # this will enqueue your job
        else
            puts "JOB not enqueue because already queued (#{job.class}, #{job.queue_name}, #{job.arguments})"
        end
    end


    def list_queued_jobs(job_class, queue_name,  arguments)
        found_jobs = []
        queues = Sidekiq::Queue.all
        queues.each do |queue|
            queue.each do |job|
                job.args.each do |arg|
                     found_jobs << job if arg['job_class'].to_s == job_class.to_s && arg['queue_name'] == queue_name && arg['arguments'] == arguments
                end
            end
        end
        return found_jobs
    end
   


end
```

Comment: This is probably very inefficient. You may want to look at this gem instead: https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to utilize this to check if all jobs or work is complete before moving on to something else, it must be noted that this is not an accurate way to measure that.

This [note](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/API#workers) regarding the worker state reporting is pretty critical:

```
Note: This data changes asynchronously, updating every 5 seconds. It is not millisecond-precise.
```

There will be a sync issue where the job has been removed from the queue, but the workers have not reported yet that the job is being processed by a worker.

For those looking to report if something is completed, the best methodology would be to set a flag in redis and unset it in the job. Wait for the flag to disappear and continue with your work.