# How can I show currently running ActiveJobs in Rails (adapter independent)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I've started some long running active jobs with `MyJob.perform_later` on `rails console`, I did not save the ids and closed the console.

I want to get a list of the currently running job ids, but I can't seem to find any way to do it in the ActiveJob API. Is saving the id/job the only way of keeping track of a job after it's sent to the queue?

I'm using sidekiq as a backend, and I can get a list of current sidekiq jobs with:

```
Sidekiq::Workers.new.each { |_p_id, _t_id, work|
  puts work['payload']['args'][0]['job_id']
}
```

This code works, and correctly shows ids of jobs that are currently running. But I want to do the same using ActiveJob api, without depending on which backend I use (so for example I can switch to delayed job without changing the code).

They also show as running on the sidekiq web panel, and I can see the ids from sidekiq, but not the active job ones.

How can I do the same with ActiveJob? I'm trying to use active-job-status gem, and I need the ID to use AvtiveJob::Status.get(job_id). I can save the ids when I start the jobs, but I'd like to show the status of all running jobs without needing to keep track of the IDs.

Comment: Your title seems misleading. Do you want the running AND the queued?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sidekiq list all jobs \[queued + running\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348723/sidekiq-list-all-jobs-queued-running)

Comment: I want the running ones, but showing all jobs no matter the status would be good too. It's not a duplicate of that question, because I know how to show sidekiq jobs (the code I used works), I'm trying to do the same with only the activejob api.

Comment: We just switched from Sidekiq to Sneakers/AdvancedSneakersActiveJob and it would have been nice to have the same thing.  Unfortunately, at this time, it does not appear that ActiveJob provides this interface.  I do not believe that Sneakers provides the functionality at all.  It might be something we have to implement on our own.