NoMethodError: undefined method `jobs' for module Sidekiq::Job
In my event service I'm trying to delete a job, but I see this:
NoMethodError: undefined method `jobs' for module Sidekiq::Job

I know that it is possible to delete using ScheduledSet, but I cannot write tests using it.
Service:
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Api
  module V1
    module Events
      class Destroy < BaseService
        attr_reader :event

        def initialize(event:)
          @event = event
        end

        def call
          cancel_notification

          event.destroy

          success!(event)
        end

        private

        def cancel_notification
          return if event.notification_job_id.blank? || Sidekiq::Worker.jobs.empty?

          Sidekiq::Job.jobs.reject! { |job| job["jid"] == event.notification_job_id }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

I tried to use Sidekiq::Workers, Sidekiq::Worker(alias) but see the same thing

Why not pass the event id to the job and have the worker fetch the event (it might do that already). If it cannot find it (because it was destroyed), the worker has nothing to do. This way, you don't have to fiddle with Sidekiq's internals.



You are checking for Sidekiq::Worker.jobs then call Sidekiq::Job.jobs? Have you checked the document for those? Are they even available?


Properly you want the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348723/sidekiq-list-all-jobs-queued-running.


But be careful, looping through the queued jobs is never be a good idea because of the race condition (the job can be added right before your loop starts)


A better approach is adding a flag to Event (say :cancelled), and the API action will set that flag to TRUE. Inside the worker, check for the flag and skip accordingly



I'm not sure where you got mentioned .all and #reject on that set from. It seems that the intent is to remove a job based on the id.
There are basically two approaches, first closes to your approach, find the job based on the jid and remove it (from how to delete a job in sidekiq):
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find_job([job_id])&.delete

This however may perform badly when you have a large queue of events to process, because internally it will just iterate all jobs (like you're suggesting), but above is more concise (cleaner code).
An alternative, and imho better, approach may be to add a cancelled(_at) attribute to the event in the database (or delete it entirely as Stefan suggested). Make sure that when the job(s) is/are picked up by the Sidekiq worker, you fetch the record, and skip additional processing there (this assumes that you're querying the database to get the latest state of the event in the job, which is general practice, and not sending all parameters to the job)
